# Can not pass this by reference, this is readonly

Tags: c#, reference, this, mutability

Getting this error message is quite confusing, as saying `this.property = value` is totally valid. quite obviously, this can be used to set values. However, when passing this as a reference into a function it errors, stating the above. How can this be passed into a function expecting a ref?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Even though you added the answer, the question is **very** unclear.

Answer (score -2):

The "this" keyword is not incredibly intuitive when being used as a parameter. The following should help clear it up.

`public void myFunction(ref myClass input) {}`

is a function which expects a reference to an instance of `myClass`, such as you would use if you intend to be able to call this function from somewhere that an instance of `myClass` may be a local variable. Quite oddly though the following throws an error

`myFunction(ref this);`

which doesn't make sense when `this` is in the definition for `myClass`. The problem arises from `this` not being a variable. Instead, it must be passed by Object. `this` is mutable, meaning functions which receive it as a parameter can alter it, and the object to which `this` refers will also change, unlike types with pass by value semantics (int, long, object, dynamic).

To solve this, create an overload for `myFunciton()` which expects `myClass` instead of `ref myClass`

**As an additional important note:** attempting `input = new myClass` will not work. It will crash your program, so never pass `this` into a function which attempts to directly set a value of its inputs. This is because you can not assign the reference this, though the properties of this are accessible and therefore can be set using this.

`this` is readonly, the properties of `this` are not. This is an unusual property unique to this, and I actually think it would be interesting if it was actually sometihng I could intentionally use.

Comment: `To solve this, create an overload for myFunciton() which expects myClass instead of ref myClass` Or do `var bob = this;` then `myFunction(ref bob);`.

Comment: “This is an unusual property unique to this”. This is true of all `readonly` properties with non-readonly fields, which are easy to create.

Comment: @mjwills No, doing so creates a layer between this and Bob, which means changes to bob do not persist to `this`

Comment: @Azeranth - yes **in the exact same way that your solution that I quoted does.** My solution acts exactly the same way as yours, but is easier to code (no need to write a whole new function overload).